# angular 2.0.0-rc1 routes and useAsDefault

Tags: routes, angular, release

has "useAsDefault" been removed in angular2.0.0-rc1?

what's the workaround? In Angular documentation i've seen using the OnInit..

Does Subroutes still work using /... notation?

Cheers

Comment: The dots from `/...` have been removed as far as I know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `useAsDefault` is not yet implemented and `/...` didn't work for me but removing did. Have you tried? Does it navigate to any route (perhaps the first) if none is provided?

Comment: yap then the comments in angular.io means usAsDefault is not implemented... and the subroutes i guess still don't work. I've tried accessing the routes but it always returns Available routes: ['/landing', '/main/...'], which are define in app.component. 
It does navigate to a route if it's nameless so  {path:'/',component:LandingMainComponent},

Answer (score 0):

Working nested routeing code for angular2: "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1" i.e. with new router are as follows:

Parent Route:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router,Routes,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import {Login} from '../login/login';
import {Dashboard} from '../dashboard/dashboard';
import {Admin} from '../admin/admin';
let template = require('./app.html');

@Component({
  selector: 'auth-app',
  template: template,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

@Routes([
  {path: '/login', component: Login},
  {path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard},
  {path: '/admin', component: Admin }
])

export class App{
  constructor(public router: Router) {
  }
}
```

Child Route

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ,Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {AddUsrCat} from './addUsrCat/addUsrCat';
import {AllUsr} from './allUsr/allUsr';
declare var jQuery:JQueryStatic;
let template = require('./admin.html');

@Component({
  selector: 'admin',
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: template
})
@Routes([
  {path: '/addUsrCat', component: AddUsrCat},
  {path: '/allUsr', component: AllUsr},
  {path: '*', component: AddUsrCat},
])

export class Admin {
  constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {
  }
}
```

Clone this project [A  basic Angular2 ("2.0.0-rc.1") project with authentication (login / logout) works as seed project](https://github.com/app4pc/angular2-bible.git) which uses **@angular/router** i.e. new route

Comment: Please do read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)

Comment: Thanks for your guide @MartijnPieters